# Aggregate a column by defined weeks in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have the following table and I need to aggregate the columns from 4 to 5 based on the defined weeks below for a given month.

```
for example for any given month my weekly definition for purchase date column as follows:

wk1: 1-6 days
wk2: 7-12 days
wk3: 13-18 days
wk4: 19-24 days
wk5: 25-31 days

Year    County   purchase_Date    acres_purchase  Date_Diff   
2010    Cache    9/28/2009        30.5                 1
2010    Cache    10/1/2009        5.0                  4
2010    Cache    10/3/2009        10.2                 3
2010    Cache    10/5/2009        20                   3
2010    Cache    10/7/2009        15                   5 
2010    Cache    10/13/2009       5                    1 
2010    Cache    10/14/2009       6                    2
2010    Cache    10/19/2009       25                   7
2010    Cache    10/25/2009       12                   3
2010    Cache    10/30/2009       2                    1


Output:

    Year    County   purchase_Date  Week          purchase_by_date  Date_Diff   
    2010    Cache    9/28/2009    Sep-wk5          30.5                 1
    2010    Cache    10/1/2009    Oct-wk1          35.2                 10
    2010    Cache    10/7/2009    Oct-wk2          15                   5
    2010    Cache    10/13/2009   Oct-wk3          11                   3
    2010    Cache    10/19/2009   Oct-wk4          25                   7
    2010    Cache    10/25/2009   Oct-wk5          14                   4
```

Is there a way that I can achieve "output" table in R?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `purchase_Date` variable is of class `Date`, you can use `lubridate::day()` and `base::findInterval` to segment your dates:

```
df$Week <- findInterval(lubridate::day(df$purchase_Date), c(7, 13, 19, 25, 32)) + 1
df$Week <- as.factor(paste(lubridate::month(df$purchase_Date), df$Week, sep = "-"))
#    purchase_Date Week
#    2017-10-01    10-1
#    2017-10-02    10-1
#    2017-10-03    10-1
#    ...
#    2017-10-29    10-5
#    2017-10-30    10-5
#    2017-10-31    10-5
```

Then, one way to achieve your target output is with dplyr like so:

```
df %>% group_by(Year, Country, Week) %>% 
  summarize(
    purchase_Date = min(purchase_Date), 
    purchase_by_date = sum(acres_purchase),
    Date_Diff = sum(Date_Diff))
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert `purchase_Date` to a date class, then extract `purchase_Day`:

```
df1$purchase_Date <- as.Date(df1$purchase_Date, format= "%m/%d/%Y")

df1$purchase_Day <- as.numeric(format(df1$purchase_Date, "%d"))
```

Define a helper function to assign each range of days to the correct week.

```
weekGroup <- function(x){
  if (x <= 6) {
     week <- "wk1"
  } else if (x <= 12) {
     week <- "wk2"
  } else if (x <= 18) {
     week <- "wk3"
  } else if (x <= 24) {
     week <- "wk4"
  } else {
     week <-"wk5"
  }
  return(week)
}
```

Pass each day to our helper function:

```
df1$week <- sapply(df1$purchase_Day, weekGroup)
```

Pull the month into a separate column, and convert to numeric

```
df1$month <- as.numeric(format(df1$purchase_Date, "%m"))
```

`month.abb` is a list of the month abbreviations. Use the numeric month to call the respective list element

```
df1$monthAbb <- sapply(df1$month, function(x) month.abb[x])
```

Combine `week` and `monthAbb`

```
df1$monthWeek <- paste(df1$monthAbb,df1$week, sep="-")
```

And @cmaher basically provided this already, but for completeness, the final summary:

```
require(dplyr)

df1 %>% group_by(Year, County,monthWeek) %>%
 summarise(purchaseDate=min(purchase_Date),acres=sum(acres_purchase),
 date_diff=sum(Date_Diff))


  Year County monthWeek purchaseDate acres date_diff
  <int> <fctr>     <chr>       <date> <dbl>     <int>
1  2010  Cache   Oct-wk1   2009-10-01  35.2        10
2  2010  Cache   Oct-wk2   2009-10-07  15.0         5
3  2010  Cache   Oct-wk3   2009-10-13  11.0         3
4  2010  Cache   Oct-wk4   2009-10-19  25.0         7
5  2010  Cache   Oct-wk5   2009-10-25  14.0         4
6  2010  Cache   Sep-wk5   2009-09-28  30.5         1
```

Comment: df1$purchase_Day <- as.numeric(format(df1$purchase_Date, "%d")) returns "Error in format.default(df1$purchase_Date, "%d"): invalid 'trim' argument. I checked my purchase date column is stored as "character".

Comment: @user3408139 you missed a quote on `"%d"`

Comment: @user3408139 also added the line to convert `purchase_Date` to a date class.

Comment: I did use the quote. it was a typo here. still gives me the error. My purchase date is stored as character.  str(df1)

Comment: @user3408139 look again, I just added the line to fix that.

Comment: I need to sum by days in each month. That means the days interval is same for every month as shown above. That means I need to sum the values in acres_purchase and Date_Diff columns falling in to the day ranges as defined.